# How to distinguish between Vuex four states

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I can't distinguish four states when I learn the `Vuex`(state,mutations,getters and actions).I can only know `'state'` is the data from components and `'mutations'` can change the state. But the other two I feel difficult to understand. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **getter** can be used essentially like a `computed` property - it can be used to work on the data in the state to manipulate it for some purpose.

For example, if your state had a list of to-do items, you could have a getter that outputs just the *completed* to-do items, or one that outputs the most important ones.

**Actions** are used when you need to do something like a mutation, but in a way that relies on an asynchronous operation. Most typically, that'll mean an AJAX request.

Your action would initiate the AJAX request, and wait for the response. When the response comes back (potentially quite some time later), the action then either commits a mutation, or directly changes the state.

You might, for example, have a `getUserProfile` action, that does an AJAX request, and when the response comes back, sets `state.user` to the data from that response.